# TCP socket function recv() blocking program

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am writing a simple TCP server program. Everything is working properly, but the function `recv()` isn't.

```
import socket
import threading

def connectionHandler(sock):
    data="#1111#Welcome on Server!"
    sock.sendall(data.encode('ascii'))
    username = sock.recv(1024)
    password = sock.recv(1024)
    print('{}, {}'.format(username, password))
    conn.close()
HOST = socket.gethostname()
PORT = 8888
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(10)
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connected by', addr)
    t = threading.Thread(target=connectionHandler, args=(conn,))
    t.start()
conn.close()
```

When I comment all calls to `recv()`, the program is working properly, but when I want to receive answers from my client (android client on a smartphone), the program is blocking itself (I think that `recv()` is waiting for the message). I know that I have to set timeout, but it doesn't solve my problem. I want to send the message first and then receive something. Why does `recv()` block `sendall()`?

Android listener function:

```java
public String listener(Socket x) throws IOException{
    try {
        Log.d("Listener","Started");
        String inp;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(x.getInputStream()));
        inp = in.readLine();
        Log.d("Listener","Ended");
        return inp;

    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return "ERROR";
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return "ERROR";
    }
}`
```

Comment: First, while I don't think this is the problem you're asking about (although it might be), it _is_ a problem you need to fix: [TCP sockets are byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html). A `recv` may get half a `send`, or three `send`s combined into one buffer.

Comment: Looking at your code more closely, that definitely _could_ be the issue. The client sends you username and password. Your first `recv` gets both. Your second `recv` waits forever for more data, but the client isn't sending any more because you already got everything.

Comment: To diagnose this, try to `print` the `username`; if it's the username and password crammed together, that's the whole problem. (And again, even if that isn't the whole problem, it's still a problem that you have to fix.)

Comment: As a side note, this is clearly Python 3. That means `recv` is giving you `bytes`, not `str`; you have to `decode` it to do anything useful. Even just `print` is going to give you `b'Franky'` instead of the `Franky` you'd want.

Comment: I know that tcp sockets are byte streams. On my client i dont receive anything. To stop program i have to hit ctrl+c twice instead of once. And after i stop program i receive my welcome message on android client.

Comment: first, if you know that, why did you write this code that can't work?

Comment: meanwhile, a recv after a send definitely can't block the send, so if that's what you think is happening, you guessed wrong. Can you show us the Android code? And tell us which lines get executed on each side?

Comment: one last thing: the reason you have to ^C twice is threading. Usually it's like this: first time interrupts the main thread, which tries to exit, which makes it block joining the worker thread(s); the second time interrupts that wait. Anyway, it's not relevant to diagnosing this problem.

Comment: `public String listener(Socket x) throws IOException{
        try {
            Log.d("Listener","Started");
            String inp;
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(x.getInputStream()));
            inp = in.readLine();
            Log.d("Listener","Ended");
            return inp;

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "ERROR";
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "ERROR";
        }
    }`

Comment: Don't try to put code into comments. They're too small, and they destroy formatting, and they're ephemeral, and they don't get taken into account in searches, and so on. It's a limitation of StackOverflow. Edit the question instead; the question should contain all the information that's relevant to solving your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Python server, you send this:

```
data="#1111#Welcome on Server!"
sock.sendall(data.encode('ascii'))
```

On the Java client, you read like this:

```
inp = in.readLine();
```

That `readLine` keeps reading until it finds a newline character. But you never send a newline character. So it keeps reading forever.

---

You have other problems that you need to fix here.

For example, your Python code assumes that TCP sockets are message streams when [they're actually byte streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html), so your `username = sock.recv(1024)` may get both the username and password, causing the next `recv` to block forever, or it may get half the username and cause a spurious login failure, or anything else you can imagine. (Of course the fact that the Android code doesn't even send either of them is an even bigger problem, but I assume you knew that and just haven't written that code yet.)

And that problem actually points to one way to solve this problem: If none of your messages are allowed to contain a newline, you can just use newlines as terminators for the messages. You're already doing this on the Java side; you just need to remember to add a `\n` when sending. On the Python side, the `makefile` method on sockets gives you a file-like object, pretty similar to what you're doing in Java, which has a `readline` method, so you can do the same thing in the other direction.

Comment: I wrote this protocol before asking here. But it didnt working as well as code i showed here. I commented second recv(), but it didnt help. Still when program is working i dont receive anything on my phone, but when i close python program (by hitting ctrl+c twice) i immediately receive "#1111#Welcome on Server!"

Comment: @Franky: I don't understand what you mean. What exactly did you write before asking here? And how could it not work as well as the code you showed here, when the code you showed here doesn't work at all?

Comment: @Franky: Meanwhile, the reason you see the data on the Android after hitting ^C^C is that the socket gets closed, and `readline` will return the last incomplete line at EOF. That isn't going to help you solve this problem, unless you want to disconnect and reconnect for every message. You need to add the `\n` on the message from the server.

Comment: That was a problem with missing '\n' on the end of string, thanks ;)